# Is it okay, resource wise, to have an infinite loop refresh a TextView (every n seconds) with a string from context.getString()?

Tags: android, loops, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines

So, I have this function:

```
inline fun runInLoop(intervalInMillis : Long = 1_000, crossinline function : suspend () -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        while (true) {
            function.invoke()
            delay(intervalInMillis)
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like so:

```
Time.runInLoop(10_000L) {
    binding.timeCreatedTextView.text = mContext.getString(R.string.time_created, 
    Time.unixToRelativeTime(item.timeCreated))
}
```

Basically, I use this function to loop every one second to refresh "timeCreatedTextView"s with DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(), and that is used the most in RecyclerView rows, so multiple infinite loops will be running on a coroutine in the background.

My question is, is anything that I'm doing potential source for memory leaks or high memory usages, since I'm using DateUtils to get the relative time, or doing string formatting every one second for however long the view is on screan?

Comment: You need to use a `CoroutineScope` that is tied to the lifecycle of your UI. As it stands, I do not see where your coroutines will ever end, and that will cause memory leaks and/or crashes.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so, the only places I use it are on a DialogFragment() (which I assume it means that when the dialog is closed, the loop no longer runs), and on a couple RecyclerViews, and I assume that when a view goes off screen and is reused, the loop is ended and a new one started. Does this work?

Comment: "which I assume it means that when the dialog is closed, the loop no longer runs" -- `CoroutineScope()` knows nothing about that dialog. Use `viewLifecycleScope` as a `CoroutineScope` tied to the lifecycle of the views in your fragment. "I assume that when a view goes off screen and is reused, the loop is ended and a new one started" -- I do not see how. You are not doing anything to cause that behavior.

Comment: I see now, I'm gonna take care of that. About the RecyclerView items going offscreen, any pointers on how i'd go about doing that? Maybe my Google-Foo is rusty, but I can't seem to find anything useful

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter?hl=en#onviewdetachedfromwindow may suffice for your needs.

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar. Could you answer my question as a top level so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a custom `CoroutineScope`. That is fine, but then it is your job to indicate when that scope is no longer needed, so it stops running your infinite-loop coroutines. Right now, you do not appear to be doing that.

A better solution is to use a `CoroutineScope` tied to the lifetime of your UI. Since you are using a `DialogFragment`, the `viewLifecycleScope` extension property on `Fragment` would be a likely choice. Then, your coroutines will be cleaned up when the fragment is destroyed. You might use that scope directly, or you might still create your own custom scope, but with `viewLifecycleScope` as a parent, so you can control individual timers (cancelling them if they are no longer needed) while still getting lifecycle awareness.